# Windows-Server-2019 - Raid 1 Software - Could not convert Disk to Dynamic security enabled on Disk

Tags: windows-server-2019, raid1, mirroring, convert, dynamic-disk

I installed a fresh Windows Server 2019 on ONE of two identical Crucial CT1000MX500SSD1M.

I don't have an integrated RAID controller on my MB ASUS_H110m-A/M.2 so I wanted to try a software RAID 1, just mirroring.

How I read everywere, is quite simple to do it, just open Disk Management and do these simple 2 operations:

- convert the Disk 0 (where Windows is actually installed) to Dynamic
- add Mirror to every volume of the disk 0 using the space of the Disk 1

In my case I always obtain the same result: "The disk could not be converted to dynamic because security is enabled in one or more partition"

Of course I tryed from command line and from graphical interface, of course I tried using both GPT and MBR schema... Nothing worked!

What's the problem?

Thanks to everybody can give me help!

[Screen of error message. Click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwEDA.jpg)

Comment: Where is the UEFI partition?? Did you do a legacy install??

Comment: Yes Michael, as you can see from the screenshot I tried to do a legacy install too.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried to do a UEFI installation (with 3 partition )but I got the same error. This last attemp (legacy install and I used original dvd) is last that I tried..